# JQuery autocomplete source from another js function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a Jquery autocomplete function whose source is calculated from another function based on `request.term` so i can not figure how to set source property right.

**Autocomplete:**

```
$( "#finder_city" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request){
        var searchParam  = request.term;
        init(searchParam);
    },
    minLength: 2,
});
```

**My function:**

```
function init(query) {
//lot of code 
return response;
```

}

My function returns valid data, like `response = [
                city1,
                city2,
                city3
            ];` but autocomplete just start "Loader icon" and nothing happens, no err in log.

Can anybody say how to set source from another js function ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) function has two params, request and a callback, once the response comes back you need to call the callback

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $( "#finder_city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, callback){
            var searchParam  = request.term;
            init(searchParam, callback)
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});

function init(query, callback) {
    ymaps.geocode(query, { results: 5 }).then(function (res) {

        var response = [];
        if (res.geoObjects.get(0) == null) {

        }
        else if (res.geoObjects.get(1) == null){
            response = [
                res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('text')
            ];
        }
        else if (res.geoObjects.get(2) == null){
            response = [
                res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('text'),
                res.geoObjects.get(1).properties.get('text')
            ];
        }
        else if (res.geoObjects.get(3) == null){
            response = [
                res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('text'),
                res.geoObjects.get(1).properties.get('text'),
                res.geoObjects.get(2).properties.get('text')
            ];
        }
        else if (res.geoObjects.get(4) == null){
            response = [
                res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('text'),
                res.geoObjects.get(1).properties.get('text'),
                res.geoObjects.get(2).properties.get('text'),
                res.geoObjects.get(3).properties.get('text')
            ];
        }
        else {
            response = [
                res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('text'),
                res.geoObjects.get(1).properties.get('text'),
                res.geoObjects.get(2).properties.get('text'),
                res.geoObjects.get(3).properties.get('text'),
                res.geoObjects.get(4).properties.get('text')
            ];
        }
        callback(response);
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xDkut/)

Comment: Hi ty now i understand. i check it on non asynchronous function and its ok. But my method is async, it load data from js api. Is there a solution for asynchronous method ?

Comment: you need to share the `init` method

Comment: I simplified it a bit, but here is code - http://jsfiddle.net/lesnick/gxW8c/ pay attention to js included in html it`s js API something like Google Maps API. Try to enter "New York" in field it will console.log() response

Comment: It works just perfect! Thank you very much! So as i understand callback have to recive data in init function, but i dont shure why. Can you provide me any links or direction to search?

Comment: @lesnick you can look at how to process async response... this is a normal scenario in ajax based development environments

Comment: +1. Are you missing a semi-colon after the call to init() though?

Answer (score 0):

In your anonymous callback, you need to return the return value of `init(searchParam)`.

Just change:

```
init(searchParam);
```

To:

```
return init(searchParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
source: function (request, response) { // Contains
    var searchString = request.term,
        array = [];

    // OPTIONS
    array.push('test 1');
    array.push('foo');
    array.push('var');

    response(array);
}
```