# jQuery autocomplete json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

Hi everyone i have an issue i want to make an autocomplete in jQuery and i have an json file in the same folder here is the code

```
var auto = $(function() {
    $("#recherche").autocomplete({
        source: "code.json",
        minLength: 1,
    })
});
```

and here is a sample of the json file :

```
{
    "__type": "Featsee",
    "feat": [
        {
            "id": {
                "ID_THING": 1111
            },
            "properties": {
                "CODTHING": "405136",
                "TIONNEMENT": "VRAC"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

the html code is the following :

```
    <label for="tags" >Recherche lot : <input id="recherche" type="text"        class="searchable" placeholder="rechercher ici"/></label>
```

the plugin is the following :

```
      <script src="libs/jquery/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="libs/jquery/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

the json file is correct but i want the autocomplete to be jus for CODTHING do you see how can i do that ??

and CODTHING is the code a want it to be the autocomplete

Comment: Please try to improve your question: What is `CODTHING`? What autocomplete plugin are you using? Which version? Can you show us some relevant HTML, please

Comment: is it understandable ??

Comment: Nopes. Not understandable!

Comment: The autocomplete looks like it's apart of jquery ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you provide to jQuery UI's autocomplete needs to be an array of objects with `label` and `value` properties or an array of strings.

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

The rest of the answer I can only guess due to the brevity of the JSON you gave us.

If `lots.json` is just a plain JS file you can look through the `feat" array in your JSON data and return strings based on that.

```
(function($){

  var lots = $.get('lots.json');

  lots.done(function (results) {

    var data = $.map(results.feat, function (lot) {
      return lot.properties.CODTHING;
    });

    $("#recherche").autocomplete({
      source: data
    });

  });

}(jQuery));
```

If `lots.json` is really a server side file that you can feed some data to and filter it there you can use a function like documented on this answer:

[JQuery autocomplete source from another js function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769001/jquery-autocomplete-source-from-another-js-function)